# Autopep8 and other modules not working after Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: python, windows, utf

I recently installed Windows 10 on my new PC and everything went fine until I encountered some issues with modules like `autopep8`. Researching the problem it didn't seem too many people have the same problem as me, so here goes my error code: `SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xdf' (...)`.

I've never seen this before and I don't want to change the `autopep8` installation files, but still would like to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that my Windows username contained the letter 'ß' from the German alphabet. As some Python (and other) modules write the installation path at the beginning of the script it tried to transfer this special char but couldn't really translate it into the right UTF-8 code.

That way Windows thought that the file wasn't properly encoded in UTF-8 and therefore threw this error.

Solution: As you can't simply rename the Windows user account (tried it, failed miserably), you have to create a new one and work with that or reinstall Windows and select a proper name.

Lessons learned: when the Windows installer asks me what my name is, I won't give it my name again.